# Magento Website Not Working (Timeout) Admin page is working

Tags: php, mysql, magento, nginx

The problem:
website suddenly doesn't load I get cloudflare "Error 524 A timeout occurred" when I try to access any page such home page/product page. What works is direct link to logo or admin panel works great. Only the main website isn't loading.

My server:
Centos 6.5 
nginx + php-fpm + percona

Errors logs:
Magento folder /var/report/

```
a:5:{i:0;s:63:"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away";i:1;s:4383:"#0 /home/webs//lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/webs//app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/webs//lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/webs//lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `tag_sum...', Array)
#4 /home/webs//lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `tag_sum...', Array)
#5 /home/webs//lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(734): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `tag_sum...', Array)
#6 /home/webs//lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(734): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `tag_sum...', Array)
#7 /home/webs//app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(521): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `tag_sum...', Array)
#8 /home/webs//lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(566): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#9 /home/webs//app/code/core/Mage/Tag/Model/Resource/Popular/Collection.php(93): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load(false, false)
#10 /home/webs//app/code/community/Gala/Opendealsettings/Block/Popular.php(49): Mage_Tag_Model_Resource_Popular_Collection->load()
#11 /home/webs//app/code/community/Gala/Opendealsettings/Block/Popular.php(72): Gala_Opendealsettings_Block_Popular->_loadTags()
#12 /home/webs//app/code/community/Gala/Opendealsettings/Block/Popular.php(89): Gala_Opendealsettings_Block_Popular->getTags()
#13 /home/webs//app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Gala_Opendealsettings_Block_Popular->_toHtml()
#14 /home/webs//app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /home/webs//app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#16 /home/webs//app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 /home/webs//app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#18 /home/webs//app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(50): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#19 /home/webs//app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/webs/pric...')
#20 /home/webs//app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#21 /home/webs//app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#22 /home/webs//app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#23 /home/webs//app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#24 /home/webs//app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#25 /home/webs//app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#26 /home/webs//app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'galaopendeal_ho...')
#27 /home/webs//app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'galaopendeal_ho...')
#28 /home/webs//app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#29 /home/webs//app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#30 /home/webs//app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#31 /home/webs//app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#32 /home/webs//app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#33 /home/webs//index.php(87): Mage::run('default', 'store')
#34 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Magento folder/var/log/system.log this both errors I can identify as part of 2 extensions not sure if this can cause such a problem but I have included it anyway.

```
2014-05-15T11:06:26+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: sql  in /home/webs/app/code/local/Webkul/Assineproduct/Model/Assineproduct.php on line 61
2014-05-15T11:06:26+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /home/webs/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml on line 13
2014-05-15T11:06:26+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: sellerscount  in /home/webs/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml on line 26
```

/var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log

```
[15-May-2014 11:11:09 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mage_Multidealpro_Helper_Data' not found in /home/webs/app/Mage.php on line 547
[15-May-2014 11:11:09 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: head_text_color in /home/webs/skin/frontend/default/galaopendeal/css/theme.css.php on line 12
```

I didn't see any errors in mysqld.log

All this errors seems minor to me can this errors cause my problem? If not how to find what really does cause my problem? I noticed the website worked few times and sometimes it's always timeout but it's slow.

Some more info: store has 65k products, also I do have most of the config files optimized for speed/traffic etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the search bar, it had sub categories under it and it tried to load a lot of categories and was timing out, Removed the search by category and it works fine! No server issues